# how do I move this default tooltip outside

Tags: tooltip, amcharts4

By default this tooltip should be Inside but I don't know how its showing inside... can anyone help me to move it outside. Thank You
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Co2l.png)

Comment: you are expecting it should be "inside" but you are also saying it is "inside" ? do you have a typo here ? and also could you please give more context to what is this regarding. I know you have added a tag arm charts 4 but it would be good improve the title and bit of code example here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute father, relative son? (Object - relationship) With the relationship created in this way, you can make the tooltip expand even outside the parent.

Comment: I found the solution https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/ 
I need to write dateAxis.render.inside = "false" to keep it outside and for inside "True"

Comment: Hey @Vincenzo Brunale , could you please add an example of code/snippet to elaborate a little as the question already is missing some context and sample code